# Date Display/entry on Apple Products

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc

In my App, i have a form that requests a start Date/Time and End Date/Time.  The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-1">
                <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <input asp-for="StartDate"   class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-1">
                <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-2">
                <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Before displaying the view, I create the start and end values something like:

```
    r.StartDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    r.EndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 58, 0);
```

This works fine on my Windows computer using Edge or Google.

When I run this same code on my phone, ipad, or Mac, it gives me an edit error saying the datetime is invalid.  I have to change the start time to 01 seconds, and the end time to 58 seconds (59 won't work).  It gives me "Enter Valid Date" error message.

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Odd thing is, it is not just safari.  If I use Chrome on an apple device, same thing occurs.

Comment: I forgot to include the model:         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")] 
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }